# Issue with Exception manage in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, exception, keychain

Hello

I would like to ask you about a problem with exception manage in a code in IOS using Swift 2.0 language.

I have the following code:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
     // Remove save value in Keychain
     let MyKeychainWrapper = KeychainWrapper()
     MyKeychainWrapper.setValue("Account", forKey: kSecAttrAccount as String)
     MyKeychainWrapper.setValue("password", forKey: kSecValueData as String)
     let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") as! LoginViewController

     self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}))
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following exception in this code:

```
2015-10-26 08:04:49.464 RapidSentryMaster[1907:25789] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<KeychainWrapper 0x7fe783922820> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key v_Data.'
```

I supposed that the exception is due because don't find any KeyChain saved previously, so I tried to managed the exception in the same way that i used to do for example in android or other languages using try..catch

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
     // Remove save value in Keychain
     do{
         let MyKeychainWrapper = KeychainWrapper()
         try MyKeychainWrapper.setValue("Account", forKey: kSecAttrAccount as String)
         try MyKeychainWrapper.setValue("password", forKey: kSecValueData as String)
     }catch{

     }
     let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") as! LoginViewController
     self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }))
```

Doing that i got the following problem:

**No calls to throwing functions occur within try expression** and
**catch block is unreachable...**

I would like to ask you, what is the correct way to manage an exception like this?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Error handling in Swift 2 is **not** meant to handle exceptions. Read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508) about it.

Comment: Thank you, so if you have to manage this exception what resources will you use to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at KeychainWrapper.h file. There is no method setValue:forKey:
Instead you should use mySetObject:forKey:
If you want try [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password) tutorial.
Cheers.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, i got your idea i solve the problem, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot encapsulate your code inside `try-catch` because **at compile time** this code isn't suppose to throw an exception to compiler.

Moreover, Swift errors are not exceptions, they act just like NSError handling with enforced handling rules.

Comment: Thank you, but i was reading something about NSError but i don't find a way to use it in that case, do you have an idea for using NSError to avoid the exception?